# SQL, Hibernate (annotations): Unable to remove parent row from table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I am getting the

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a
>   foreign key constraint fails

when trying to remove a row.

It seems that I have incorrectly mapped the relations.

Starting from the top:

I have to entities. ElectricityMeter and ElectricityReading.

Since I only want to know to which meter each reading belongs I decided to have ManyToOne unidirectional relation which is as below:

Reading:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ELECTRICITY_READING")
public class ElectricityReading {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column
private int id;
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
ElectricityMeter meter;
//some other columns 

    public ElectricityMeter getMeter() {
        return meter;
    }

public void setMeter(ElectricityMeter meter) {
        this.meter = meter;
    }
//other getters setters etc.
```

Meter:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ELECTRICITY_METER")
public class ElectricityMeter extends {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column
private int id;
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String serialNumber;
  //some other columns 


//getters setters etc.
```

As for my knowledge the **"@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})"** should do the trick and allow me to remove the parent row (meter) and trigger to remove all the readings that belong to the meter in scope yet it does not occur.
It gives me the the error instead.

How should I properly map the entities so that I will be able to remove the parent row as well as to remove orphaned rows at the same time?

Stack is below. Unfortunately I wrote the program in Polish and the classes above have been translated on the go.
Words that appear in stack:

odczyt- reading;

licznik- meter;

energia- electricity;

```
  exception

 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
 processing failed; nested exception is
 org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not
 execute JDBC batch update
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:659)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
 root cause

 org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not
 execute JDBC batch update
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:92)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:87)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:222)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2484)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2702)
    org.hibernate.action.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:77)
    org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
    org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
    org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:172)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    kamienica.dao.LicznikDaoImpl.deleteLicznik(LicznikDaoImpl.java:68)
    kamienica.service.LicznikServiceImpl.deleteLicznik(LicznikServiceImpl.java:58)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:108)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.deleteLicznik(Unknown Source)
    kamienica.controller.LicznikController.usunLicznikEnergia(LicznikController.java:121)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
 root cause

 java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a
 foreign key constraint fails (`kamienica`.`odczyt_energia`, CONSTRAINT
 `FK55CB21B13D42C17B` FOREIGN KEY (`licznik_licznik_id`) REFERENCES
 `licznik_energia` (`licznik_id`))
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1213)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:912)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:92)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:87)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:222)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2484)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2702)
    org.hibernate.action.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:77)
    org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
    org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
    org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:172)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    kamienica.dao.LicznikDaoImpl.deleteLicznik(LicznikDaoImpl.java:68)
    kamienica.service.LicznikServiceImpl.deleteLicznik(LicznikServiceImpl.java:58)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:108)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.deleteLicznik(Unknown Source)
    kamienica.controller.LicznikController.usunLicznikEnergia(LicznikController.java:121)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Appreciate your help,
Maciej

Comment: You don't need to show us the entire stack trace.  Where is the code where you do the delete?

Answer (score 1):

`CascadeType.ALL` on `ElectricityReading` means that all relevant actions are cascaded *from* the reading *to* the meter, not the other way round. So if you delete a meter no cascading is happening.

To solve that just add the other direction with cascading as well and add the `orphanRemoval = true` attribute to the annotation. Won't need any change on the database since `ElectricityReading` is still the owner of the relation.

If you don't want to do that, you'd have to manually delete the corresponding readings first.

Comment: I'll try with that. Thanks.